# Active Directory Password Overlap

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Is there a way to configure active directory so that when a user changes their password their previous password will work for a few hours?  Basically want to have a grace period during a password change where both the old and new password will work.

Comment: would prefer not to hack the registry but this looks promising http://support.microsoft.com/kb/906305

Comment: What would be the reason for needing this? The password change is going to bite at some point, so is it not better to have a short pain? Also, be wary of this little sentence in the kb article you linked to: "Existing components that are designed to use Kerberos for authentication are not affected by this change."...

Comment: "The extension of the password lifetime period applies only to network access by using NTLM. Interactive logon behavior is unchanged." Not that promising :P

Comment: @JR: Absolutely. Which is why I posted my answer. It sounds to me like the OP wants users to be able to log on with both passwords, which isn't possible that I'm aware of.

Comment: that seems very ... wrong :-|

Comment: This sounds like a bad dream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this registry change worked for me http://support.microsoft.com/kb/906305

Answer (score 6):

No............................